# Send Post Request to the https URL with username and password in linux

Tags: linux, curl, https, http-post

I need to send a post request to the https(Certificate) URL in linux,
URL have username and password.

is it possible? if it is how? if it is not, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Curl data:

```
curl --data "username=value1&password=value2" https://dzaczek.com/resource.php
```

you need check webside variable name and post address

Answer (score 0):

In Linux with curl tool I have used next:

`curl --data "delay=0sec" https://username:password@localhost:8080/job/Test/build`

Like you see you only need insert into address `username:password@` and here is one param which is named as `delay` with value `0sec`.

It helps me post request to jenkins server.